# PIC outputs while programming

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

Does anyone know what the state of the PORT pins are on a PIC when flashing the part?  I am running a [PIC 16F916](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41250E.pdf) with an ICD3 programmer, and the IO pins are performing various functions, and need to understand what state they are in during programming when the PIC is energized.

Answer (score 7):

In the datasheet for your microcontroller there are four tables, table 2-1 to 2-4, which describes all the registers, including `PORTx` and `TRISx`.

The tables have a column named **Value on POR/BOR Reset** and **Value on all other Resets** which describes the register state at startup and after resets.

As you can see for `TRISA` up to and including `TRISD`, the state is **`1111 1111`**, which means that the pins are configured as *inputs*, or in other words, put the corresponding output driver in a High-impedance mode.

Unless I'm completely mistaken, the programming mode should *not* change this, except for the pins relevant to programming.

Comment: Thanks.  I am configuring the part to use the MCLR pin as an input so it is internally tied to VCC.  I guess programming falls into the category of "all other resets?"

Comment: @JohnBirckhead I'm not familiar with the ICD3 which is why I had to "guard" my answer with "Unless I'm completely mistaken", but even _if_ you can use the ICD3 to program the Flash without resetting the device, you must at least have the option of manually causing a reset before programming, if you want to make absolutely certain that the ports are tristated.

Comment: I'm with you - I am just going to change the design to allow activation of MCLR.